# How to use if else ladder in android while dealing with radio buttons

Tags: android

The following is the code that I am currently using in the `OnClick` method for using a radio button.

```
switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.op1_radio_button:
        if (checked) {
            score=0;
            break;
        }
```

I am looking for an `if-else` version of the code so that it would be easier for me to use radio buttons.

Comment: In android studio, click on `switch` keyword, then hit `Alt+Enter`, then select "Replace 'switch' with 'if'"

Comment: *it would be easier for me to use radio buttons* no it will not be easier

Comment: why not use the switch is it wrong try not to escape by workaround understand everything please in the code you write and solution as @NabinBhandari mentioned

Comment: What's wrong with using a `switch` statement?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
    int id = view.getId();
if(id == R.id.op1_radio_button){
//do something
}else if(id == R.id.button2){
//do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use RadioGroup to manage RadioButton selection like this in your XML,

```
        <RadioGroup
        android:checkedButton="@id/rbtn_male"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbtn_male"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Male" />

            <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbtn_female"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Female" />
</RadioGroup>
```

now, to manage the click on RadioButton in Your Activity add this,

```
        RadioButton rbMale = findViewById(R.id.rbtn_male);
        RadioButton rbFemale = findViewById(R.id.rbtn_female);

        rbMale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    score = 1;
                    }
        });

        rbFemale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    score = 0;
                    }
        });
```

I hope this is the best answer for your case.